# Advantage of using generating functions in analyzing an algorithm

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, recurrence-relation, generating-functions

I'm reading through the first chapters of "Introduction to the analysis of algorithm" by Sedgewick. I wasn't familiar with the use of generating functions, and complex analysis in general to analyse algorithms. I do understand the use of the tool is in practice simple (at least it seems to me in that way from what I read so far).

I still don't get though what's the particular advantage of using a generating function over standard techniques of difference equations when analysing some recurrence extrapolated by some algorithm.

What's the benefit of using generating functions?

I can also see "analytic combinatoric" as topic, I haven't read through that yet, what's the advantage of that formalism instead? Is there some case where analysing in that way is really easy while using standard technique isn't?

Comment: Perhaps you should keep reading the textbook.

Comment: Of course I'll keep reading... But just for sake of not missing the point of all this, is it hard to provide an example?

Answer (score 3):

Generating functions can be used to solve recurrence relations more complicated than linear recurrence relations with constant coefficients. As an example, let us consider quicksort (credit: [lecture notes of Rezaul A. Chowdhury](https://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~rezaul/Fall-2017/CSE548/CSE548-lecture-7.pdf)). Let us denote by $t_n$ the average number of comparisons performed by quicksort when the pivot is chosen at random. We have $t_0 = 0$ and for $n \geq 1$,
$$
t_n = n-1 + \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n (t_{k-1} + t_{n-k}) = n-1 + \frac{2}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} t_k.
$$
Some work shows that the generating function $T(z)$ of the $t_n$ is
$$
T(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty t_n z^n = \frac{2\log \frac{1}{1-z} - 2z}{(1-z)^2}.
$$
From this it is not hard to extract the formula
$$
t_n = 2(n+1)H_n - 4n.
$$

In this particular case, there are more direct ways to calculate $t_n$. However, in more sophisticated situations, such tricks might not work. Furthermore, generating functions lead to mechanical manipulations - in fact, a software package can probably convert the recurrence for $t_n$ to the generating function, and hence to the exact expression. In this sense, generating functions generalize linear recurrence relations with constant coefficients by providing a large class of recurrences whose asymptotics can be ascertained.

Comment: Is there a relationship between generating function and the $Z$- transform used in DSP? from the definition they look the same, and as far as I've seen this is used mostly for linear difference equations with constant coefficients. I remember the avarage case analysis for the quicksort in CLRS that was quite difficult.

Comment: It's basically the same thing.